# vscode css class detector if it's available in style.css

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

i have an index.html that contains my html with tailwindcss classes, i also have custom classes on style.css file, sometimes when i add classes to div element, i do use wrong classes that are not exist in style.css and i spent minutes or sometimes hours to catch the bug.

example :

```html
<div class="w-full bg-prim shadow-md py-4 flex flex-col px-12 hover:h-96 transition-height duration-500 ease-in-out spacey-4">
</div>
```

let's say spacey-4 is not exist in style.css and it's a wrong class.

well here is how is happened to me, i spent 3 hours today, solving a UX bug, because i used a wrong class by mistake, , i didn't realized when i added a character to a class, and then it crashed the UX

is there a vscode extension that will detect this error, like underline it if it's not exist!

Comment: How is it related to HTML, CSS and Tailwind-CSS?

Comment: because i'm using HTML with TailwindCss and sometimes i do use fresh css. in the same project, please remove that -1 because i'm really suffering with this bug.

Comment: This is not how tag system works. If you are making a website with Python and MySQL for backend and have a doubt related to CSS, you won’t put all 5 tags, i.e, HTML, CSS, JS, Python and MySQL, but will only add CSS and in some cases HTML tags.

Comment: And that -1 vote is not for the mistake of tags but for other things.

Comment: check my edit now, and you'll have the idea of what i want to acheive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, BUT I would recommend you the "css peek" extension. If you  click ctrl (or in german strg) and hover over a class or an id (in html code) it shows you the css of the element and if the element has not got css you know that.

I hope I could help you

Comment: thanks for your reply, i do have that one, but i do prefer to have an extension that will do the job without hovering on the class name

Comment: Yes I know. I'm sorry but I don't know any extension like that.

Comment: Anyways, thanks i'll leave later a solution if i find one, or maybe develop an extension for that, well i spent 3 hours today, solving a UX bug, because i used a wrong class by mistake, , i didn't realized when i added a character to a class, and then it crashed the UX.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could try IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML extension for VSCode which is [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

It's not validate the css class name as you typed, but it suggests the drop-down intellisence and if the css class you're trying use is not in the list, you know what to do.

Tks.